# Fusion Tables using php Login required Error 401 when inserting

Tags: google-fusion-tables

This is what i try to do. select command work but when try to insert it generate
    error "Login required Error 401"  any example where insertion, updation and deletion  is done without this type of error
    or any other suggestion which help me

query(SQLBuilder::insert(44444, array('grefid'=>3000, 'distname' => 'xxxx', 'tehsilname' => 'bob')));

    ?>

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to get the API key...visit the following link to get the same:

[Get Google API Key](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)